# Inserting huge data from one to another table and simultaneously deleting after movement using pyodbc package in Python file

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to use SQL Server and Python to perform data migration and deletion.
However, during the process of execution, I find it hard to reconcile the data which is being inserted in new table in a loop is also moving the same data and also deleting the same data in a batch of 1000. I mean the exact rows.

In my below code, there is a loop which inserts data into new table and statements below that deletes the records which are in that batch size.

```
While True:

            query = f"insert into [{table_name1}] ({column_names})" \ 
                    f" SELECT {column_names}" \
                        f"FROM {database}.{table_name2}"  \
                        f"WHERE {table_name1.date} = '{table_name2.date}'" \
            try: 
                cursor.execute(query)
                cursor.commit()
            except:
                break
                
            delete_query = f"DELETE FROM {database}.{table_name2} where {table_name1.date} = '{table_name2.date}"
            cursor.execute(query)
            cursor.commit()
```

my question is that the movement and delete is working good. However, I want to put a condition where rows that are moved are the only ones that are being deleted in a loop of 1000.

The above code is inserting x and deleting y data, however, for the same date.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [OUTPUT ... INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause with the DELETE to insert the deleted rows into another table in single statement.  eg:

```
delete from TableA
output deleted.*
into TableB
where SomeColumn='20101229'
```

And note that individual SQL statements are implicitly wrapped in a transaction.  So even without an explicit transaction, this is guaranteed to be an "all-or-nothing" operation.